# I can add multiple stopwatch but i can't make then run parallel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need an app that loads multiple stopwatches but with my file, I can add multiple stopwatches but I can't make them run parallel.

When 2nd one starts it reads the 1st one's data and starts from there and stops the previous one.

Tried several ways, but can't seem to resolve it.

```js
var row_id = $('#hidden_row_id').val();
output = '<td>' + name +
  ' <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name[]" id="name' + row_id +
  '" class="name" value="' + name + '" /></td>';
output += '<td><span id="output' + row_id + '">00:00:00</span> <input type="hidden" name="hidden_time[]" id="time' + row_id +
  '" value=""/></td>';
output +=
  '<td><button type="button" name="remove_details" class="btn remove_details" id="' +
  row_id + '"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td>';
output +=
  '<td><a class="btn" id ="startPause' + row_id + '" onClick="startPause(' + row_id + ')"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a><a class="btn" id="reset" onClick="reset(' + row_id + ')"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></a></td>';
$('#row_' + row_id + '').html(output);

var time = 0;
var running = 0;

function startPause(i) {

  //var info = this.i;
  if (running == 0) {
    running = 1;
    increment(i);
    document.getElementById("startPause" + i).innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-pause'></i>";
  } else {
    running = 0;
    document.getElementById("startPause" + i).innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-play'></i>";
  }
};

function reset(i) {

  running = 0;
  time = 0;
  document.getElementById("startPause" + i).innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-play'></i>";
  document.getElementById('output' + i).innerHTML = "00:00:00";
  document.getElementById('time' + i).value = "00:00:00";
};

function increment(i) {
  if (running == 1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      time++;
      var mins = Math.floor(time / 10 / 60);
      var secs = Math.floor(time / 10 % 60);
      var tenths = time % 10;
      if (mins < 10) {
        mins = "0" + mins;
      }
      if (secs < 10) {
        secs = "0" + secs;
      }
      document.getElementById('output' + i).innerHTML = mins + ":" + secs + ":" + "0" + tenths;
      document.getElementById('time' + i).value = mins + ":" + secs + ":" + "0" + tenths;
      increment(i);
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: My bad, I am new here, just added tags to to get attention to the issue that's all

Comment: For future reference, don't do that. Tags are there so people know what the question is about, and people subscribe to tags and when they find that those tags are not actually relevant to the question, you just risk downvotes and annoyed people (which is the opposite what you want when asking for help)

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for the suggestions. I will keep that in mind

Comment: Could you add *some* HTML to your snippet to make it runnable? Also, sharing a code  attempt to solve it yourself will get you more answers.